# Need a regex for .h or .cpp

Tags: regex

I need a regex for finding all .h, .c, and .cpp files in a folder. Help?

[no, this isn't homework, I just don't have time to learn regexes right now]

Comment: Care to tell us a language ? Are you sure you don't mean `glob` ?

Comment: You cannot enumerate a directory with a regex.

Comment: @SLaks, he never said he's in the shell.

Comment: @Matthew: So what?  You still can't enumerate a directory with a regex.

Comment: @SLaks, sure you can.  To give a trivial example, repeatedly call readdir and check whether the filename matches before doing something.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, but that requires something other than a regex.  He needs to specify a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
\.(h|c(pp)?)$
```

But do you really need a regex?  Where are you using this?

Comment: You actually save 1 character by explicitly including "cpp" and it's slightly easier to read! I'd probably have done the same thing though, just because it's cooler.

Comment: @Mark, true, but consider what happens if c++ and cxx are added. ;)

Comment: Yes, but it's still 3 more than `\.(h|c(pp|xx|\+\+)?)$`, @Amarghosh :)

Comment: May be, but mine looks more cool (read obfuscated/hard to read) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/\.h$|\.c$|\.cpp$/
```

You can also write it like this:

```
/\.(h|c|cpp)$/
```