# Filter for .h and .cpp files (kdevelop)

Tags: c++, regex, kdevelop, filefilter

on kdevelop, you can configure a file filter ( on top of project tree ). Normally, the project tree shows a lot of files with different extensions, e.g `xy.conf, xy.prf, moc_xy.cpp, moc_xy.h` and so on. I want hide all unnessary files with following regex: `[^\moc][a-z]*\.(h|cpp)`. But if I use this regex, it shows me no files. Whats wrong with this regex?

I also, read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893645/need-a-regex-for-h-or-cpp) but the answer: `\.(h|c(pp)?)$` doesn't work.

Best regards, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only show `*.h/c/cpp` files in your project by first excluding all files `*` and then adding these inclusive patterns for them.

Like this, e.g. add this to your `.gitignore`/`.hgignore` file:

```
*
!*.h
!*.c
!*.cpp
```

If you don't have such filter files, you can configure them in the kdevelop's project fileter by adding includes and excludes:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you, where can i find the `.gitignore` file or should I create a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @user2372976 Here I assume you're using git/hg to svn your code. Updated the answer by adding how to make it within kdevelop.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.(h|c(pp)?)$
```

it works when i tested it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: That's true, but if I paste it into the file filter field on kdevelop, the project tree will not update. This regex works: `[^\moc][a-z]*.cpp`.